# live tv stream to ipad 1 or 2 using vlc command line and html5 from analog TV card on ubuntu linux

Tags: linux, ipad, html, stream, vlc

My system:
I run ubuntu natty, and have an old analog TV card, the winTV-go +FM. and vlc 1.1.9., apache2
What I want to achieve:
take the output of my old tv card, stream it with vlc and have the stream embedded on a local site to be displayed with html5, so i can watch the stream on my ipad 1 or 2
Current situation:
I have managed to get streaming with vlc working (i don't use the gui) with different containters and codecs. I have 3 working stream-commands that include:

```
1: vlc -vvv v4l2:///dev/video0:width=640:height=480 :input-slave=alsa://hw:1,1 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mp3,vb=8000,ab=128,channels=1,samplerate=44100}:standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=192.168.1.10:9090}'

2: vlc -vvv v4l2:///dev/video0:width=640:height=480 :input-slave=alsa://hw:1,1 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=theo,acodec=mp3,vb=8000,ab=128,channels=1,samplerate=44100}:standard{access=http,mux=ogg,dst=192.168.1.10:9080/test.ogv}'

3: vlc -v v4l2:///dev/video0:width=640:height=480 :input-slave=alsa://hw:1,1 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=1024,acodec=mp3,channels=1,ab=128,samplerate=44100}:standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=192.168.1.10:9080/test.mp4}'
```

I can open all 3 streams on a different computer and play them in vlc, Note on the side: the *.ogv stream i can also just enter as an url (http://192.168.1.10:9080/test.ogv) in chrome and it displays it there as a video, the other 2 streams it tries to download as a file.

So far so good, now I come to my html5 code (had some trouble pasting it here, so i used pastebin to dsiplay the code):

[pastebin html5 code](http://pastebin.com/JgZbBhLq)

this works perfectly in chrome, but because it is ogv it will of course not work on the ipad, so i need to use h.264/mp4 as that is supported/built in with safari, but when using the stream command 1 or 3 then i get no video displayed on ipad or chrome.
When not using stream-command 2 (the ogv command) I adjust the html5 code to one of the following (I have tried all 3):

```
  <source src=http://192.168.1.10:9080/test.mp4 type=video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp3"'>
```

or

```
 <source src=http://192.168.1.10:9080/test.mp4 type=video/mp4'>
```

or

```
 <source src=http://192.168.1.10:9080/test.mp4'>
```

none of these work.

I have also added mime types to my /etc/mime.types

video/mp4                                       mp4
video/quicktime                                 qt mov
video/mp4v-es
video/ogg                                       ogv
video/webm                                      webm
video/x-matroska                                mpv mkv
application/x-mpegURL                           m3u8
video/MP2T                                      ts
application/x-mpegURL .m3u8

how do I have to specify the html5 code for it to be properly displayed on my ipad? anyone got a clue?
btw I have also tried http apple live stream using ffmpeg and segmenter and i get that working as well, but due to the fact that TV is a continuous stream of data it does not work well with the playlist, so i stops after a while and you need to restart etc, not very handy and i want the above working, would appreciate the help, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

For HTML5 and h.264 you have to use AAC as the audio codec and mp4 as the mux, where you are currently using mp3 for audio and TS for mux. That said, I don't have VLC live streaming via HTML5 video working yet.

iPad viewers of my live web show are watching via the oPlayer free app on my h.264/AAC/FLV stream that I also use for Flash clients, but I'm hoping to get HTML5 live streaming to work.